# Blend 4 - Regenerate 'Create Sample Data from Class' when class changes

Tags: expression-blend, blend, expression-blend-4

Using Blend 4 I know how to generate sample data using the 'Create Sample Data from Class...' option in the Data tab.  This creates a .xaml file in a SampleData folder that I can use to populate my UI in design time.

My question is how do I regenerate this XAML file when I change the base class that this .xaml is based on?  I added a new C# property called 'Clients' and it shows up in the Data tab after I rebuild, but I do not see how to regenerate the XAML sample data to include data for this property.

I would rather not scrap the entire sample data and recreate it as that would require me to re-setup the data types on each property again (Number, 3 words, Address, etc).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. As far as I know the setup of the datatypes is not stored anywhere. The sample data for the string format you select is written to the file immidately. And only if the type is defined in the sample data xaml file. The only thing you can do is adding the new property by hand and than select a format for it.